# Laravel 4 migrate rollback problems

Tags: php, laravel

I can easily run the artisan migrate etc, but when i try to roll it back, with migration:rollback i keep getting this error,

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\laravel>php artisan migrate:rollback
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'CreateCodesnippetsTable' not found","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illum
inate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator.php","line":301}}
```

Is this a bug? or how should i debug this?

Comment: Please provide the migration files, for the migrations you are trying to rollback

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z5c7nvZd (listed)

Comment: How is your CodeSnippetsMigration file named? Did you happen to change this or the class name manually?

Comment: I've had the same problem. But in my case it failed on a migrate:reset/migrate:refresh. the problem was, that I deleted a migration-file but the table migrations still contained an entry for this file, so artisan was unable to rollback this migration due to a class not found error. I deleted this entry from the migrations table and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 177):

Maybe you've already solved this issue. But I'm noticing that for some reason a rollback often requires you to run `composer dumpautoload` first. Even if your migration works.

Comment: The documentation lacks this tidbit. (http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)

Comment: You flippin' genius. Had me foxed for an hour.

Comment: why we need to run composer dumpautoload ?

Comment: We need composer dump-autoload because migrations are just a bunch of classes which are autoloaded during process of running them up / down. However php artisan dump-autoload did not show composer.json error, while composer dump-autoload did.

Comment: In my case, I had not installed composer on this machine yet. (Copied the entire directory when reinstalling linux.) So, while migrate:make runs dump-autoload, it was not executing on my local machine since I didn't have composer. Installing composer and running dump-autoload worked.

Answer (score 37):

Having just wrestled with this problem for several days, I think I can now provide the **definitive** answer to solving this problem. Yeah, big call I know, but bear with me.

The first port of call if you encounter this problem is to run `composer dump-autoload`. This should result in an updated version of the file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.

If `autoload_classmap.php` doesn't get updated then you may have a permissions problem, in which case you could try `sudo composer dump-autoload`.

However, if `autoload_classmap.php` *does* get updated, check that it contains an entry for your migration class (in this case `CreateCodesnippetsTable`). If there is no entry for this class then you should check your `composer.json` file and make sure the `app/database/migrations` folder is included in the autoload section, eg:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations"
    ]
},
```

This last bit is what screwed things up for me. In a misguided attempt at optimising things I pulled as much as I could out of my `composer.json` file, naively thinking this would only affect web requests. It turns out this affected Artisan as well, so putting this line back in and running `composer dump-autoload` fixed the problem for me.

Finally, if all that fails, then *maybe* there's a bug in one of the supporting libraries that is causing the problem, in which case you can try updating using `composer update` or some variation thereof. However, I suspect that this will rarely be the true cause of the problem.

Comment: Lack of autoload changes can also mean bad syntax on `composer.json`. You'll know that when running `composer dump-autoload` on your main project, but when running `php artisan dump-autoload`, a syntax error on a `composer.json` in your workbench won't be alerted. If your workbench projects are acting up, `cd` into them and try to run `composer dump-autoload` individually.

Answer (score 13):

If you are in windows, simply use *composer* in your terminal/command line utility and do the following:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

From what I can see I am guessing you have changed the class name manually.
In the error you have the class name `CreateCodesnippetsTable` but in the migration file  you provided (pastebin), the class name is `CreateCodeSnippetsTable` (notice the S in Snippets, I guess that is what you changed manually).

If you check the migrations table in your database you will see records for each migration. When you create the migration it will be saved in the database with that name and the rollback method tries to read the file with the name provided in the database, in the case when you change it manually laravel can't find the class and you get the error.

To fix this you can undo the changes and try to rollback or manually edit the migration row in your database to include the correct class name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to me there are no single solution of this error. I have tried many suggestion but at last this one works in my end.

```
COMPOSER=composer.json composer dump-autoload
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by running

`composer.phar update`

Comment: no need to update the dependencies, since the only thing required is to dump the autoloaded files and regenerate them when updating, this task is also done at last, but no need to do a complete update of dependencies, if not needed to. just run the command 'composer dumpautoload' or 'composer.phar dumpautoload' and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

download the **composer.phar** file from laravel site and bring the **composer.phar** file to the *root directory* of  laravel folder,

then from terminal come to the root directory of laravel and run the `composer.phar update`  or simply run `php artisan dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem and figure out the problem

I've created a migration for adding new column date in PatientReasonOfVisits table 
i used laravel generators 
when i create the migration the class name was

```
class AddDateToPatientReasonOfVisitsTable
```

sure after creating a new migration file u need to run composer dump-autoload to ensure the file is listed in class map file

the file name was
2014_09_02_214134_add_date_to_patientreasonofvisitstable.php

the migration done successfully
and a new record has been added into migration table.
in migration column the file name is used

when i rollback the migration 
i got the class not found exception what class is not found 
this one

```
AddDateToPatientreasonofvisitsTable
```

note : the difference between classes names

why and how i solved this problem 
i guess when u rollback the class name resolved using the migration file name which in migration table 
the capital and small letters is decided by underscores "_" in file name

so after renaming the migration file to 
2014_09_02_214134_add_date_to_patient_reason_of_visits_table.php
and sure run composer dump-autoload after renaming the file 
the class name resolved correctly with no exception

Answer (score 0):

I simply dropped the migrations table then ran `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Then the migrations were all able to execute, not sure if that's the best method, but it worked for me.

I'm running Laravel 5.