# Phpunit Laravel 5.1 - Error trait DatabaseMigrations - Don't refresh the database

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I have a test file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class AdsTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function test_it_one()
    {
        $ad = factory(App\Ad::class, 2)
            ->create( [
                'firstname' => 'jeremie',
                'lastname' => 'ges'
            ]);
    }


    public function test_it_two()
    {
        foreach (App\Ad::get() as $value) 
        {
            var_dump($value->slug);
        }

    }

}
```

I want to rollback after each test my database to avoid false positives and false negatives. So I used the trait `DatabaseMigrations`, but it doesn't work, the method `test_it_two` outputs that:

```
[15:13:56] PHPUnit 4.8.18 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Starting test 'AdsTest::test_it_one'.
.
Starting test 'AdsTest::test_it_two'.
.string(11) "jeremie-ges"
string(9) "test-test"
string(11) "test-test-2"
string(13) "ergerg-regerg"
string(11) "test-test-3"
string(13) "jeremie-ges-2"
string(10) "rgreg-regr"
string(13) "jeremie-ges-3"
string(13) "jeremie-ges-4"
string(13) "jeremie-ges-5"
string(13) "jeremie-ges-6"
string(13) "jeremie-ges-7"
string(13) "jeremie-ges-8"
string(13) "jeremie-ges-9"
string(14) "jeremie-ges-10"
string(14) "jeremie-ges-11"
string(14) "jeremie-ges-12"
string(14) "jeremie-ges-13"
string(14) "jeremie-ges-14"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**Solved**: Before to run your tests, take care to have a clean database, $ artisan migrate:refresh does the trick ;)

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test, I can use databaseMigrations as they said in the documentation ...

Comment: so you can. Dunno what to tell you. Not a laravel guy

Comment: Thus q/a might help (even if it's for v4) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174463/laravel-4-migrate-rollback-problems good luck

Comment: Glad i could help. If one of the answers over there helped, be sure to give them an upvote!

Comment: Also bear in mind that, to have your **development local DB** separated from **PHPUnit testing DB** you can configure separate DBs. So when you run PHPunit it always uses a clean DB schema and so you don't need to run `migrate:refresh`. I've configured this [in my project like so](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/master/phpunit.xml#L25). [See reference here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-specify-a-testing-database-in-laravel-5)